# Lightline and airline with neodark.vim

Tags: vimrc

I have installed the [neodark.vim](https://github.com/KeitaNakamura/neodark.vim) plug-in by Keita Nakamura following [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/41720/47095) answer.
Currently my .vimrc looks like this:\

[image]

But the lightline theme doesn't appear on the status bar:
[image]

What is wrong here and how can I fix it?

**Edit:** I have updated to:

```
:set number
:set relativenumber

call plug#begin()

Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim' " lightline
Plug 'KeitaNakamura/neodark.vim' " vim-plug

call plug#end()

set termguicolors " recommended
colorscheme neodark

let g:lightline = {}
let g:lightline.colorscheme = 'neodark'
```

and did :PlugInstall

But, the issue persists.

Comment: Textual data (like the snippet of your .vimrc) is best inserted as text, e.g. between the "code fences". See the [edit] instructions. I would blindly guess you need to install the [lightline.vim](https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim) plugin before you can use it. With your newly gained knowledge on plugin managers you could figure out a way.

Comment: I fail to see, what this has to do with airline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install lightline.

Add to your `.vimrc` (between `call plug#begin()` and `call plug#end()`:

```
Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
```

Make sure `laststatus` is set to 2

```
set laststatus=2
```

Restart Vim

Run `:PlugInstall`

Restart Vim

Comment: I did this, but nothing happened. Still not working ;(

Comment: You have to set laststatus to 2 (I have updated the answer).